# Can the achievements dialogue say more than just "+2 tag wiki"?

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, achievements-dialog

When one earns reputation from making tag wiki edits, the achievements dialogue, shown when hovering over one's username, just says `+2 tag wiki`. There is no indication of which tag wiki was edited, or whether it was a tag wiki or a tag wiki excerpt. This gets particularly silly and useless if one edited several tag wikis at the same time, filling the list with entries that just say `tag wiki`, `tag wiki`, `tag wiki` over and over.

Can the achievements dialogue say `[tagname] tag wiki` instead? It links to the right tag wiki, so it knows which tag the suggested edit was for, but I have to click through or look at the status bar to see which tag it was.

[image: picture of achievements dialogue]

Comment: It would be nice to make it look like the user profile page, which already shows "_tag-name_ tag wiki" and "_tag-name_ tag wiki excerpt".

Answer (score 19):

This is a pertinent issue, since one expects some kind of standard to be applied when it comes to the way that information gets presented across the different areas of each SE site.

Looking at the "activity" tab, under "suggestions" we get the information presented as follows:

[image: Activity - Suggestions]

This information is expected to be equally presented to the user on other areas of the site, as to allow a user to better relate with the information between the several places where he sees it.

If we look at the reputation details or the reputation summary, as mentioned in the question, one can't relate with the information presented on the users activity tab.

[image: User reputation]

This poses an extra effort from the user's part, since AFAIK there's no way one can get to know what does the `+2 tag wiki` refers to unless we click, get directed to another page, having then to get back to where we were.

It's odd that since we have so many user-friendly features across every SE site, this one isn't considered and appears to have been "neglected", while it's safe to say that this sure is an important one, from the users point of view, as well as from the site consistency point of view.

### Let's implement/solve this!!

Answer (score 2):

I agree with this FR here's a more extensive example from today:

[image: screenshot achievements dialogue with tag wiki events]

Here's an example from 2 days ago (screenshot collated because the events don't fit in a single dialogue):

[image: screenshot achievements dialogue with tag wiki events]

A noteworthy comparison is that in the edit history for the review queue the events are shown with titles and with the difference between wikis and excerpts:

[image: screenshot of suggested edit review queue history]