# Add tag name to "tag wiki" edit descriptions

Tags: feature-request, edits, tag-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Activity dropdown for tag wiki suggested edits do not display tag's name](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84893/activity-dropdown-for-tag-wiki-suggested-edits-do-not-display-tags-name)

Instead of just "tag wiki", how about making it say something like "tag wiki for [not-an-answer](/questions/tagged/not-an-answer)"?

They're already linked to the relevant tag wiki, so it might as well indicate which one that is.

[image: user dropdown]