# Why was I given reputation twice for the same Tag Wiki?

Tags: support, reputation, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

Someone asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351903/error-could-not-save-type-string-into-variant-double-pal#comment28698405_19351903) which moved me to edit their question and add a new tag called `pal`. Later after, I edited this tag wiki and added some information about it. Now, I look at my reputation, and I'm credited twice in a row for the same edit. So instead of 2 rep, I gained 4 rep. Both these occurrences are also at slightly different times (6 minutes apart).

[image: Rep shows same thing twice]

When I look at my activity, it also shows...

[image: Activity shows same thing twice]

Why was this counted twice?

Comment: Wiki and excerpt probably... it's annoying that they're the same...

Comment: They show up correctly in the reputation summary on your main profile.

Comment: Related: [Can the activity dropdown say more than just “+2 tag wiki”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84893/can-the-activity-dropdown-say-more-than-just-2-tag-wiki)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You got 2 points for the excerpt and 2 points for the description.

The time lag was because they both were approved through the review process at different times.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but look at the picture I added in my edit - it shows both of them that the body was edited.

Comment: @JerryDodge, yes, the body of the description, and the body of the excerpt.  I'll change the language in my answer.

Comment: I didn't see the `description` and `excerpt` at first, now I do